# Azure B2C - Using Single Sign Out returns 302 status code instead of 200

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-ad-b2c

To preface, I **do** have SLO working for my apps, using logout URLs, OIDC JWT tokens with B2C custom policies, etc.

However, from [this Microsoft doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/session-overview):

**Applications must respond to this request by clearing any session that identifies the user and returning a 200 response.**

Unfortunately, using the following code for silent logoff (code mostly taken from a Microsoft B2C sample) I receive a 302 back with what appears to be the app's OIDC PostLogoutRedirectUri value.  Despite my efforts to force a 200 OK return, it's still sending back a 302 to the browser with the redirect.  Is there a quick fix I need to make to my code to make it stop the redirect?

```
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult LogOffSilent()
        {
            var authTypes = HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
            HttpContext.GetOwinContext().Authentication.SignOut(authTypes.Select(t => t.AuthenticationType).ToArray());
            Request.GetOwinContext().Authentication.GetAuthenticationTypes();
            HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = 200;

            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
```

Comment: do you mean SSO with SLO? I understand your app is replying with a 302 instead of 200. Is that correct? Can you share all the relevant OIDC code and config?

Comment: Hi Alfredo, thank you for your reply.  I ended up logging a ticket with MS Support a few days back.  A few hours ago they informed me that the 302 is expected, because the signout is redirecting to the b2c logout method.  So I guess there's nothing more to be looked at here.